When to use 对 and 对不对
So firstly I must apologise as I am about two weeks into a Duolingo course - so I would say my understanding of the language is near enough 0.
However, I wanted to ask if someone could clarify some examples of when you would use 对 and 对不对.
It is my understanding that they both mean the same thing, is one more formal than the other?
E.g. 对我是老师！ and 你是老师，对不对？
Could you also say 对不对我是老师 or is that now becoming incorrect?
(Apologies if I am missing any grammar!)

"对" is used in reply confirming something is right/correct = Yes, it is correct.
"对不对" is used in inquiry = correct or incorrect?

你是老师，对不对？- You are a teacher, correct (or incorrect)?

对, 我是老师 - Correct, I'm a teacher.



That’s great. I thought that would likely be the case - thanks for confirming.

Actually, “你是老师，对不对？” is very similar to a tag question.
你是老师，对不对？

You are a teacher, aren't you? (Written English)
You are a teacher, right? (Spoken English)

对，我是老师。

Yes, I am a teacher.

See also: https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/Tag_questions_with_%22bu%22
There are variants with "X + 吗" instead of "X + 不 + X" (X can be 对/是/好/可以）:
你是老师，对吗？is roughly equivalent to 你是老师，对不对？
See: https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/Tag_questions_with_%22ma%22
